# How to handle multiple input field changes by a single function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `form` in which 2 fields, and on click i want to save fields data into the state object.

I don't want to make different function for every input field on change.

**Code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Todo extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        data : {
            "name":'',
            "option":'',    
        },
    },
        this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
    }

    inputChange = (propertyName,e) => {
        this.setState({});
    }

    handleForm = () => {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        console.log(this.state.data.name);
        console.log(this.state.data.option);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleForm}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" name="name" value={this.state.data.name} onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this, "name")} />
                    <select name="option" value={this.state.data.option} onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this, "option")}>
                        <option> Select Option </option>
                        <option value="1"> Option 1 </option>
                        <option vlaue="2"> Option 2 </option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

> The object initializer syntax also supports computed property names.
>   That allows you to put an expression in brackets [], that will be
>   computed and used as the property name.

Use this:

```
inputChange = (propertyName,e) => {
    let data = {...this.state.data};
    data[propertyName] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ data });
}
```

Working Code:

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data : {
        "name":'',
        "option":'',    
      },
    },
    this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
  }

  inputChange = (propertyName,e) => {
    let data = {...this.state.data};
    data[propertyName] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  handleForm = () => {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    console.log(this.state.data.name);
    console.log(this.state.data.option);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleForm}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" name="name" value={this.state.data.name} onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this, "name")} />
            <select name="option" value={this.state.data.option} onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this, "option")}>
                <option> Select Option </option>
                <option value="1"> Option 1 </option>
                <option vlaue="2"> Option 2 </option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: in my code i can't even type in input fields i don't know why ?

Comment: that was because you are using the [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), and not updating the state value because of that fields became read-only, use the function i suggested, it will work properly.

Comment: i use that like you did still can't type

Comment: sorry i missed an important part, you are storing the value inside data object, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the react tutorial:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {email:''};
    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleEmailChange(event) {
  this.setState({email: event.target.value});
 }
  
  render() {
  return(
    <div>
       <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" 
          value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />  
    </div>
    );
  }
  

}
```